# Vuetify select append indent in front of item

Tags: vuetify.js

Is there any way to add indent in front of select item in Vuetify select component? Usually when I'm using default select HTML tag I can use something like `&nbsp;` to  append one or more indent in front of option ex:

```
<select>
   <option value="0">Root</option>
   <option value="1">&nbsp;Category-1</option>
   <option value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Sub-Category-1</option>
   <option value="3">&nbsp;Category-2</option>
....
</select>
```

But it's not work with Vuetify select component. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieve by adding `\xA0` with option values.

```
items: ['Foo', 
        '\xA0Bar', 
        '\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0Fizz',
        '\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\xA0\Buzz'],
```

Response:[image]